# Android app retrieving data from MySql database?

Tags: android

Can an android application retrieve data from a remote MySql database and show the retrieved data within the app canvas? I own a website whose articles remain stored in MySql database, i want the app to retrieve data from my website's database and show the article in any particular fashion? Is there a way out?

Comment: please show us what you have tried first

Answer (score 1):

If your website already uses the own database, instead of querying any data remotely you can retrive data from your website's fields or tags such as `<div id="bodyTag">...</div>` by using [**`Jsoup`**](http://jsoup.org/download) HTML parser library.

Comment: You can type `Document document = Jsoup.connect("yourURL").get();` to connect your website's specific area, then typing `Elements body_text = document.select("div[id=bodyTag]");` will retrieve the tag field.